# TinyMCE image uploader and paths

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE editor and imagemanager to edit pages here. For backup reasons i also have to store a copy of uploaded images in the database. 
So after reading the TinyMCE doc i started editing the _Template.php file to biuld my own plugin, and it's stored in

```
$HOMEDIR\js\tiny_mce\plugins\imagemanager\plugins\CacheToDb\CacheToDb.php
```

my problem is that i want to access my common functions and classes in "my" $HOMEDIR/inc/ form within CacheToDb.php; however i have problems to point back to /inc/class_database.php from

`$HOMEDIR\js\tiny_mce\plugins\imagemanager\plugins\CacheToDb\CacheToDb.php`.

I tried to add the following lines on top of ChacheToDb.php

```
define('__ROOT__', "../../../../"); 
require_once(__ROOT__."inc/global.php");
require_once(__ROOT__."inc/class_database.php");
```

Going up 4 folders here because it's apparently included from

```
$HOMEDIR/js/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/index.php
```

However, this dosnt work. Every time i try require_one() i always get an empty window when i click the "add image" button in TinyMCE, so i assume a php error message breaks the json response...? Firebug did not reveal any obvious bugs or usefull info at all.
Anyone who had this issue before and know how to include a path without breaking the whole thing?

Comment: ok, i found a solution, and there is a bit more to it than just getting a path right: 

- in js\tiny_mce\plugins\imagemanager\classes\ManagerEngine.php , line 204, replace 
`if ($config["authenticator"] == "")` 
with 
`if (empty($config["authenticator"]))`

for some reason, this line caused an error when i included my own global.php. Also, calling session_start() inside my global.php broke the TinyMCE image manager.

- my db class etc. has to be included in js\tiny_mce\plugins\imagemanager\config.php, because config.php, so it available to all the other plugins etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a closer look into the servers error log in order to check what the error is.